# How does the cross multiplication of Quadratic Equation work?

Tags: polynomials

How does the cross multiplication of Quadratic Equation works?

If:
$$f_1\left(x\right)=a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$$

and:
$$f_2\left(x\right)=a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2=0$$

have a common root, let's say, $\alpha$, then by the method of cross multiplication:

$$\frac{\alpha ^2}{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}=\frac{\alpha }{c_1a_2-c_2a_1}=\frac{1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$

How does that work??

Answer (score 4):

The vector $v = (\alpha^2, \alpha, 1)$ is orthogonal to both $w_1=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $w_2=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ and assuming that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are independent this implies that $v$ is a multiple of the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) $w_1 \times w_2$.  That's precisely what these equalities express.

Comment: I don't think that explains the algebra very well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question (for those who wonder how this comes out : )

We have:

$$f_1\left(x\right)=a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$$

$$f_2\left(x\right)=a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2=0$$

Multiply $f_1\left(x\right)$ by $a_2$ and $f_2\left(x\right)$ $a_1$ then use elimination method to obtain one part of the answer.

Then mulitply $f_1\left(x\right)$ by $b_2$ and $f_2\left(x\right)$ by $b_1$ and similarly use elimination method to obtain the second part and then equate all of them simultaneously.